# Update JSON value in array of objects

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently, I came across a problem where I needed to update/modify JSON data stored in database column 'Column1'

Sample Data Column1:

```
{'fields':[{'id':1,'name':'product 1'},{'id':2,'name':'product 2'},{'id':3,'name':'product 3'}]}
```

Working on below query but could not make it work.

```
UPDATE c
SET Column1 = JSON_MODIFY(Column1, '$.name', '{new name}')
FROM TestTable c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.Column1, '$.fields' )  p
WHERE JSON_VALUE(p.value, '$.name') = 'name'
```

If someone can point me to right direction with any links, I will be thankful. Current query is operating on first item, I just need it to be able to work for all array items.
Thanks for you time.
Lot of people talking about not using the query to update JSON at all.

With this query I am getting:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'b' is found at position 0.

But when I replace `"$.fields[0]"` with `'$.fields'`, it updates 0 rows

Comment: BTW, your posted JSON is not actually valid JSON (according to a strict interpretation of the JSON specification) as your property names are not enquoted.

Comment: to be honest, i am not good at sql queries, just trying to learn for my current problem.

Comment: _"Current query is operating on first item, I just need it to be able to work for all array items."_ - your current query has `fields[0]` hardcoded - how will you specify other array indexes in future?

Comment: originally i needed something similar to this query, taking first index item wasnt intended for long term query, 
update c
set Column1 = JSON_MODIFY(Column1, '$.name', '{new name}')
from TestTable c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.Column1, '$.fields' )  p
WHERE JSON_VALUE(p.value, '$.name') = 'name'

Comment: You've changed your question though - I'm unsure how exactly you want things to work without exact array indexes, but here's my T-SQL for updating single elements: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f9e85/2 - I hope you can use that as a starting-point.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will try it out, please post it as answer